# NestJs - Apply middleware excluding some routes of controller

Tags: node.js, nestjs, middleware

I want to apply middleware only for some routes of controller. I have been searching for a long time but still I am unable to get the solution

My controller code

In the below code I want to apply middleware exluding '/create' and '/login' routes.

```
@Controller('/driver')
export class DriversController {
  constructor(private readonly service: DriversService, private readonly validator: DriverValidator) {}

  @Post('/create')
  async createDriver(@Body() driver: DriverDto): Promise<any> {
    return this.service.createDriver(driver);
  }

  @Post('/login')
  async loginDriver(@Body() body) {
    await this.validator.validateDriverLoginInForm(body)
    return this.service.loginDriver(body);
  }

  @Get('/get/products')
  async getProducts(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.service.getProducts();
  }
```

My middelware applying code

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .exclude() // what should I write here
      .forRoutes(DriversController);
  }
}
```

Please help me. I am new to nest js

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation provided by NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#excluding-routes). It explains really well how you can exclude routes.

There are 2 ways to do this, one is just adding the path to an array, and the second one is creating an object in the array defining the path and method. The latter one is useful when you have 2 paths that are the same, but with different request methods.

So example 1:

```
exclude(['/driver/create', '/driver/login'])
```

And example 2:

```
exclude(
  [
    { 
      path: '/driver/create', 
      method: RequestMethod.POST 
    }, 
    { 
      path: '/driver/login', 
      method: RequestMethod.POST 
    }
  ]
)
```

---

But as you're new to NestJS, here's a head start for your example:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .exclude(
        [
          {
            path: '/driver/create',
            method: RequestMethod.POST
          },
          {
            path: '/driver/login',
            method: RequestMethod.POST
          }
        ]
      )
      .forRoutes(DriversController);
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works!